# WCF REST Service with Generic Collection

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am attempting to build a Restful WCF Service. In my WCF Service I am referencing 1 dll which contains the Data Access Layer.

I have the following method in my WCF class

```
public class Search : ISearch
{

    public List<Product> GetProductList()
    {
        ProductDA dataAccess = new ProductDA();
        List<Product> obj = new List<Product>();
        obj = dataAccess.GetProducts();
        return obj;
    }

}
```

My interface holds the OPerationContract as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISearch
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "getProductList",  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    List<Product> GetProductList();
}
```

When I run the url http://localhost:36741/RestService/Search.svc/getFoodTruckNameList in the browser I receive the following error:
The server encountered an error processing the request

Does anyone know the correct code to call the [OperationContract] for `List<Product> GetProductList();` ?

Thanks in advance. Been pulling my hair out on this one for a while..

Comment: That error generally means your code threw an exception. Have you tried debugging your web service?

Comment: You need to get some more details on the error, try attaching the debugger and post the exception details. Heres my simple example on how to set up/configure WCF to use rest which might give you some pointers http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/02/using-rest-wcf-service.html

Answer (score 3):

Looking at my RESTful web services that do something like this, I typically do something closer to:

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class Products : List<Product> 
{
    public Products(IEnumerable<Product> products) : base(products) { }
}
```

Then your interface would be like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISearch
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "getProductList",  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    Products GetProductList();
}
```

And then your service contract would look like:

```
public class Search : ISearch
{
    public Products GetProductList()
    {
        return new Products(new ProductDA().GetProducts());
    }
}
```

Comment: My only confusion here is the first section                           [CollectionDataContract] 
      public class Products : List<Product>  
    { 
     public Products(IEnumerable<Product> products) :  base                (products) { } 
} 
My WCF Service is referncing a dll that holds the Product data objects and the DAL. Is that where the above code would be?

Comment: That is where I put it in my projects, but if you prefer to put it in your BLL then it would probably work there too.

Comment: I prefer to keep the DLL with the data object and DAL alone. Still confused on this part but I will take a look later this evening and see if I can get it working..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

We have often had problems returning a Generic list as the response to a WCF service.

The simple way to solve it is to create a class which has a single property which is the Generic list, and then return this class.

```
[DataContract]
public class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Or just have your custom class inherit from `List<T>`. This will keep it from producing more levels of XML than necessary.

Comment: @Shiraz I think you are on the right track. Could you post a code snippet to create the class which has a single property which is the Generic list, and then return this class? Thanks man...

Comment: @M. Babcock You also I thnik are heading in the right direction from what I researched previosly. Could you post the code where to inherit? I mean it wouldnt be public class Search : ISearch : List<Product> right?

Comment: @midnightCoder - Added answer with what I mean.